# how to make a 2-digit string from an integer using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

In python, how can an integer representing for a day or month be converted to a 2-digit string? e.g. 2 --> '02' and 12 --> '12'

Is there any way to format this string with re?

Comment: regular expressions are not suited for string **formatting/building.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, you can use format codes

```
>>> '%02d' % 5
'05'
>>> '%02d' % 12
'12'
```

`%d` is the format code for `int`, then `02` says to print the number to 2 digits of precision, and pad the left with `0` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.format` function.

```
>>> '{:02d}'.format(2)
'02'
>>> '{:02d}'.format(12)
'12'
```

If you really want to use regex, then use `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', '2')
'02'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', '12')
'12'
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.